# Can python write multiple columns under a principal column to a csv?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I would like to be able to write multiple columns under one principal columns in a csv, i don't know if it's possible. I would like it to look like this image write here :
[image: CSV]

Comment: checkout pandas [multiindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.html)

Comment: As mentioned, you can probably create the structure in Pandas, but your output won't be a valid CSV, as it does not have a "column span" syntax.  If you output to plain csv, and import to Excel, the `10DC` column will not span 3 columns.  Do you wish to save data directly in Excel ? This is possible using [OpenPyXL](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2020/11/03/openpyxl-working-with-microsoft-excel-using-python/).  Note that **CSV != Excel** just because the .csv extension is associated with Excel.

Comment: CSV does not support nested structure, so no.